# [IE issues]Bold line appear in row of table

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

I have a table with multiple row same struct.

```html
<table width="40" style="font: 8pt/normal Verdana; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal;" bgcolor="black" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
 <tbody>
  <tr bgcolor="#ffff80">
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#ffff80">
   <td>11:00</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr bgcolor="#ffff80">
   <td>11:20</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr bgcolor="#ffff80">
   <td>11:40</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr bgcolor="#ffff80">
   <td>12:00</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr bgcolor="#ffff80">
   <td>12:20</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr bgcolor="#ffff80">
   <td>12:40</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr bgcolor="#ffff80">
   <td>13:00</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr bgcolor="#ffff80">
   <td>13:20</td>
  </tr> 
 </tbody>
</table>
```

[ie11bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNJbg.jpg)
what is the bold line? If i add more lines It seem to appear randomly. How i can avoid it. Thank you.

Comment: Since running this snippet in FF produces the same effect, I'd suspect the bug is in your html. have you considered setting the `bgcolor` on the `<td>`rather than `<tr>`?

Comment: @Filburt       It is still the same.